# asp.net c# aspx if statements not working

Tags: asp.net

I do some asp programming, but have not worked with asp.net or aspx scripts.
I am trying to create a script that will send an html file if a cookie is not set, but send a pdf if it is.  I keep getting a runtime error.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
HttpCookie mycookie = Request.Cookies["CHECK"];
if (mycookie.Value == ""){
 Response.ContentType = "text/html";
 Response.Clear();
 Response.TransmitFile("forbidden.html");
 Response.End();
}
else
{
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.Clear();
 Response.TransmitFile("test.pdf");
 Response.End();        
}
%>
```

I have tested the response code block for the html and the pdf and both work fine and sends the files to the browser. I added the line that sets mycookie with the cookie information and it still works.  When I add the if logic, I get a runtime error.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

If `Cookies["CHECK"]` is not set, then `mycookie` will be `null`. Therefore you probably get a `NullReferenceException`.

Try the following:

```
if (mycookie == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(myCookie.Value))) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

And welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I added this line and it gave me: error CS0117: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrEmpty'

Comment: Please retry using `String` with a capital 'S'.

Comment: It wasn't me... if you want to know :)

Comment: This gave me: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'myCookie' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). By the way, there was an extra ) in that code.  I can't believe it is this hard to read a cookie and check the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if mycookie is null.

Try something like:

```
if (mycookie == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(mycookie.Value)){
```

Comment: Actually, your first answer was wrong, you were not validating mycookie for null... so why the -1?

Comment: @Dennis, although it was an unnecessary answer, there is no need to be rude

Comment: @freefaller True. Sorry. Will remove my comment but keep the -1

Comment: @BrunoCosta because it merely restates what has been stated in other answers before.

Comment: :) I love comments and voting!  Personally, I only rate negative if the answer is incorrect.  You never know how long it took the person to write their response or what they saw on their screen when they started.

Comment: @jtimperley This probably is what happens when people see inline code. They feel the urge to pick a fight ;) I mean look, every answer has been downvoted (not all by me)! I'll take mine back, because it's silly. May OP decide who should get the tick.

Comment: You're welcome, sorry again. There are users just fishing for points by simply restating what has been posted already. I'm sure you're not one of them.

Comment: This gave me: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'myCookie' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: @tjd Don't forget C# is case sensitive. Can you try with mycookie, perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

I mean, that better is:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
HttpCookie mycookie = Request.Cookies["CHECK"];
if ((mycookie != null) && (mycookie.Value == "")) {
 Response.ContentType = "text/html";
 Response.Clear();
 Response.TransmitFile("forbidden.html");
 Response.End();
}
else
{
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.Clear();
 Response.TransmitFile("test.pdf");
 Response.End();        
}
%>
```

Comment: This will probably do the wrong thing. It will execute the else-block if `Request.Cookies["CHECK"]` evaluates to `null`.